# bx slider doesn't load

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I'm trying to implement a bx-slider in my website. 
I have downloaded the bx slider files and saved them in a folder named "js"
I'm having trouble loading the slider, can someone please help

My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Swan Lake Paradise</title>
  <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
    <script src="/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
    <!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
    <link href="/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="main">
<div class="page">
<div class="header">
    <a href="index.html" title="Home"/>
<div class="header-img">
</div>
<div class="menu">
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="Services.html">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="Gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="Attractions.html">Attractions</a></li>
  <li><a href="Contact%20Us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
<div class="left-panel" style="width: 800px;">
<div class="left-panel-in">
<h2 class="title">Gallery</h2>
<br>
    <ul class="bxslider">
        <li><img src="../images/logo.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="../images/Dilshan.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="../images/google-maps.jpg" /></li>

    </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: could you please try putting the `script` initialising the `.bxSlider()` plugin just before the closing tag of `body`? also, check your console window of developer tools of your browser to see if there are any issues.

Comment: @TahirAhmed I put the script initialising the .bxslider() just before the closing tag of the body but still no luck. I checked the console and it says "GET file:///C:/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Gallery.html:15
GET file:///C:/lib/jquery.bxslider.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Gallery.html:11 
GET file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Gallery.html:66 
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: so you are working locally. append `http:` to the `src` for jQuery, that should resolve the jQuery file not loading issue at least. for the others, you may not have placed the files in proper locations as it seems.

Comment: @TahirAhmed thanks that worked

Answer (score 0):

Hello Chamara Dilshan,

I test your demo and its working fine for me.

Can you check your all files and its path that you used in your code.

And please download the latest JQUERY file then use in your code...

Let me know if any trouble you face

Good Luck .. ['}